# Map with Purrr multiple dataframes and have those modified dataframes as the output

Tags: r, purrr

I've got a question with the map function from the Purrr package.

- I can successfully pass on a list of data frames to a function using map
- the output remains a list and that's my issue ; I need to have the modified data frames as R objects

As an example with the mtcars dataset:

```
#I create a second df
mtcars2 <- mtcars 

#change one variable just to distinguish them 
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg / 2

#create the list
dflist <- list(mtcars,mtcars2)

#then, a simple function example
my_fun <- function(x) 

{x <- x %>%

    summarise(`sum of mpg` = sum(mpg), 
              `sum of cyl` = sum(cyl)
    ) 
}

#then, using map, this works and prints the desired results
list_results <- map(dflist,my_fun)
```

But, I would need to have the modified mtcars and mtcars2 saved as r objects  (dataframes).

- Should I add a "save" option of some kind to my function ?
- Should I use map_df or dmap ? (My trials were unsuccessful)

In advance, thanks a lot to all of you !

Comment: It is better to keep it in a `list`.  But, if you need to have multiple objects in global env, then check `?list2env`

Comment: @David I'm not understanding your question, does `map_df(dflist, my_fun)` not work?

Comment: If you are trying to access the resulting dataframes then you need to subset into the list i.e.    list_results[[1]] . Tbh though I am struggling to understand the question exactly sorry.

Comment: @Cpak: it does work but it returns a single dataframe ; I need to keep the split between them. Thanks !

Comment: @CroGo : this should work indeed but I'd like to have the resulting dataframes to replace the original ones and be as df already.

Comment: @akrun ; this is indeed the function I needed! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars2 <- mtcars 
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg / 2
dflist <- list(mtcars,mtcars2)
```

To save the objects one would need to give them specific names, and use:

```
assign("name", object, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

here is one way to achieve that:

```
my_fun <- function(x, list) {
  listi <- list[[x]]
  assign(paste0("object_from_function_", x), dflist[[x]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
  x <- listi %>%
    summarise(`sum of mpg` = sum(mpg), 
              `sum of cyl` = sum(cyl)
    )
  return(x)
}
```

`my_fun` has two arguments - `seq_along(list)` to generate specific names and the `list` that is to be processed

this saves two objects `object_from_function_1` and `object_from_function_2`:

```
list_results <- map(seq_along(dflist), my_fun, dflist)
```

another approach would be to use `list2env` outside of the map function as  akrun suggested

```
dflist <- list(mtcars,mtcars2)
names(dflist) <- c("mtcars","mtcars2")
list2env(dflist, envir = .GlobalEnv) #this will create two objects `mtcars` and `mtcars2`
```

and run `map` after you have created the objects as you have already done.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I've tried the second option and it worked like a charm !!!! Thanks a lot for the first option, I'll definitely use it in the future !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using `purrr::walk()` with `get()` and `assign()`. Similar to those above, but not identical.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data(mtcars)
```

Create the second data frame.

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg / 2
```

Create the function to apply to each data frame.

```
sum_mpg_cyl <- function(.data) {
  .data %>% 
    summarise(
      `sum of mpg` = sum(mpg),
      `sum of cyl` = sum(cyl)
    )
}
```

Apply `sum_mpg_cyl()` to `mtcars` and `mtcars2`, saving two data frames of summary stats by the same names to the global environment. A potential advantage of this method is that you do not need to create a separate list of data frames.

```
walk(
  .x = c("mtcars", "mtcars2"),
  .f = function(df_name) {
    # Get the data frame from the global environment
    df <- get(df_name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    
    # Calculate the summary statistics
    df <- sum_mpg_cyl(df)
    
    # Save the data frames containing summary statistics back to the global 
    # environment
    assign(df_name, df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
)
```

I would probably also use an anonymous function and save the two data frames of summary stats with different names like this:

```
# Reset the data
data(mtcars)
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg / 2
```

```
walk(
  .x = c("mtcars", "mtcars2"),
  .f = function(df_name) {
    # Get the data frame from the global environment
    df <- get(df_name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    
    # Calculate the summary statistics
    df <- df %>% 
      summarise(
        `sum of mpg` = sum(mpg),
        `sum of cyl` = sum(cyl)
      )
    
    # Rename the data frames containing summary statistics to distinguish
    # them from the input data frames
    new_df_name <- paste(df_name, "stats", sep = "_")
    
    # Save the data frames containing summary statistics back to the global 
    # environment
    assign(new_df_name, df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
)
```