# Apply map function to grouped data frame in with purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, split, purrr

I am trying to apply a function which takes multiple inputs (which are columns which vary depending on the problem at hand) and applying this to list of data frames. I have taken the below code from this example: [Map with Purrr multiple dataframes and have those modified dataframes as the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140756/map-with-purrr-multiple-dataframes-and-have-those-modified-dataframes-as-the-out) and modified it to include another metric of my choosing ('choice'). This code, however, throws an error:

> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : unused argument (choice = "disp").

Ideally, I would like to be able to create a grouped data frame (with group_by or split() and apply a function over the different groups within the data frame, however have not been able to work this out. Hence looking at a list of data frames instead.

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars 

#change one variable just to distinguish them 
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg / 2

#create the list
dflist <- list(mtcars,mtcars2)

#then, a simple function example
my_fun <- function(x) 

{x <- x %>%
  summarise(`sum of mpg` = sum(mpg), 
            `sum of cyl` = sum(cyl),
            `sum of choice` = sum(choice))}

#then, using map, this works and prints the desired results
list_results <- map(dflist,my_fun, choice= "disp")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things to fix the code above:

1. Add `choice` as an argument in your function.
2. Make your function have an output by removing `x <-`
3. Use [tidyeval](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) to make the "choice" argument work.

The edited code thus looks like this:

```
my_fun <- function(x, choice) 

{x %>%
summarise(`sum of mpg` = sum(mpg), 
          `sum of cyl` = sum(cyl),
          `sum of choice` = sum(!!choice))}

list_results <- map(dflist, my_fun, choice = quo(disp))
```

If you want to stay within a dataframe/tibble, then using [`nest`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) to create [list-columns](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls13_list-columns.html) might help.

```
mtcars2$group <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 32, replace = TRUE)
mtcars2 %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    nest(-group) %>% 
    mutate(out = map(data, my_fun, quo(disp))) %>% 
    unnest(out)
```

Comment: As of rlang 0.4.0, it is also possible to use `sum({{choice}})` within the function (curly curly), which drops the need to quote the variable of choice explicitly when calling the function.